# Is there a way to insert data that returned from a method in Java into an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I'm confused to find the solution. I built some methods and at the end I built a `toString()` method to collect all data from the other variables and I want to store it into an Array or ArrayList. I want to build many different values from each variables. But they have a same Object.

Example :

```
public String toString(){
    return "Text" + variableX + "Text" + variableY;
}
```

How can i store it? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you cram everything into a `String`? Just return an array or `List` from your method if you need the data in that form. It's not clear what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: In the result "Text" will be the same everytime or not?, If yes then we can use "Text" as delimit to break string and collect data into arratList

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you have a string with some values contained in it and all the values contained in it needs to be inserted into an ArrayList.

If you're concatenating different values into a string, you'd need to follow a pattern to be able to extract them later. For example, you may want to delimit each value with a hyphen (-) or something else. Then, you can extract each value as a string by splitting the string with the delimiter using the split method on String. If you want, you can even convert the values into appropriate data type from the string before inserting into the ArrayList.

I hope it is helpful!